# How many short urls can be generated per day for Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest
The document says "Requests are limited to 5 requests/IP address/second, and 200,000 requests/day.".

So which is correct?
"200,000 total times per day" or "200,000 times per 1 IP Address per day"??

Answer (score 0):

Look at it more like, `5 requests/IP address/second` as a rate - you can't exceed that number of requests sent per IP address per second.

Whereas `200,000 requests/day` is the total limit of requests you can send per day.

So, you're probably looking for the answer as 200,000 total requests per day.

If you require it, you can request to increase your quota using this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfPS2BfT5x9nwYrnQIrqu8Pzgcy2XF45Uv8ZsqBoL4RFEoQNg/viewform).

> Enter the following fields to request the increase in Firebase Dynamic Links API quota. We have default spread quota (200,000 queries per day) and burst (500 queries per 100 seconds). Consider spreading your load over a longer period of time before requesting.